# Crear jar desde pom

Tags: java, maven, jar

Tengo un proyecto donde al ejecutar el comando mvn clean install me crea el correspondiente war del proyecto, pero ahora necesito tambien contar con el jar del proyecto donde el proyecto esta dividido en distintas capas.

He agregado al pom el plugin correspondiente

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>

                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Pero al ejecutar maven no consigo crear el jar, ademas me figura por consola la siguiente notificacion:

> --- maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:test-jar-no-fork (attach-sources)
>   No sources in project. Archive not created.

Puede estar faltandome algo definir?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "el jar del proyecto donde el proyecto está dividido en distintas capas"?

Comment: Cuando digo capas, por ejemplo en una capa tengo los .java que pertenecen a la capa de controladores, otra capa para los servicios, otra para los archivos web

Comment: No, si eso está claro, pero ¿cómo lo has organizado? Deberías tener un módulo maven distinto (con *packaging* de tipo *jar*) para cada cada capa, y el maven del *war* tendría una dependencia a éstos. ¿Es así? Por lo que muestras, no está claro.

Comment: Lo más probable es que tu estructura de carpetas no sea estándard. Por favor comparte la estructura para ayudarte a ver por qué tu plugin manda un mensaje indicando que no halló código fuente.

Answer (score 0):

Para crear el .jar del proyecto es únicamente necesario ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
$ mvn package
```

Comment: Estoy usando el plugin maven-source-plugin, he conseguido poder crear un jar con los archivos .java pero no consigo consigo poder incluir los archivos .jsp, .css etc que estan en webapp, como tampoco puedo conseguir incluir un idrectorio afuera del root del proyecto, a alguien se encontro con este tipo de problema?